# What is the Rust time type that is the best fit for a distributed environment?

Tags: rust

I read the documentation of [`std::time`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/index.html) and discovered that there are 3 types of time available:

- [`Duration`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/struct.Duration.html)
- [`Instant`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/struct.Instant.html)
- [`SystemTime`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/struct.SystemTime.html)

I need the implementation which is closest to [RTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_clock) with almost no clock drift. I need to use the times across machines in a distributed system.

I thought of going with `Instant`, but then I also [read this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/struct.Instant.html):

> Note, however, that instants are not guaranteed to be steady. In other
>   words, each tick of the underlying clock may not be the same length
>   (e.g. some seconds may be longer than others).

Which one is the best fit for a distributed environment?

Comment: Note that Rust differentiate between a duration ("This action took 3 hours and 27 minutes to execute") and a moment in time ("This action was executed on the 3rd of June 2004, at 14:56"). `Duration` represents the former, `Instant` and `SystemTime` the later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are essentially two approaches for distributed communication of time points:

1. Use [PTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_Time_Protocol) to synchronize time across your various machines and assume that the precision is sufficient for your application; you should be able to reach micro-second precision which is generally good enough.
2. Do not use a global time, instead:

   - Mark each different machine as a different time-source (or even, each different *core*),
   - Tag each event with its time-source and its instant,
   - Never attempt to compare instants from different time-sources.

In either case, `Instant` is better (monotonic) than `SystemTime`. `SystemTime` is weird since the time can be rewind, which is generally unexpected.

Comment: How to make use of PTP? Any examples in Rust?

Comment: @RajeevRanjan: You generally do not have to use PTP from any language; PTP is a service running on the computer which synchronize the computer time. For example, see this project for [PTP in Linux](http://linuxptp.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: What if I were to run my distributed system on Dockers,AWS,etc ? Would it still be possible? Would I need to install a driver in that environment if at all possible?

Comment: @RajeevRanjan: I am sorry, I have no experience with Docker (or AWS) so I do not know. You would have to ask on the relevant venues.

Answer (score 1):

Of the three, `Instant` seems like it would give you the closest approximation of a RTC, at least within the context of the system.

In a distributed sense, you'd probably want to have only one instance across one machine and query it on the others to get relative time, that way you are guaranteed at least consistency in event times.

After a cursory glance, I was unable to find an out of the box solution if you want accurate time.